# Umask for root and other system users

Tags: umask

If I am not wrong, this is how umask is calculated.

```
for dir,  777 - 022(root's umask value) = 755.
for file, 666 - 022(root's umask value) = 644.
```

Now, where this umask value is defined? Is it the `/etc/bashrc` file?.

If so, then what is the file `/etc/login.defs` for?
My `/etc/login.defs` file says 077 as umask - what does this mean?

Also where is cmask defined?

The umask can be changed using umask command, but that is temporary. Right?
If I have to make it permanent, I can edit `.bashrc` file in my home dir and append "umask value" to it.

Also, say I am root and I want to set a specific umask for all other users, how to do that?

Comment: Umask is actually applied using bit operations: `0777 & ~022`. Does Wikipedia or any other search result for `umask cmask` or `umask login.defs` answer your question?

Comment: Nope. I can't find a proper answer. Thought posting in public forum might help. Will try finding answers anyway and if i am successful, will update the same here.